# Rails test JS view from controller spec

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've got a controller action that responds with a `js` response.  This `js` response actually renders another partial.  I'd like a controller test in case the partial or `js` file ever has an error.

controller:

```
class ZonesController < ApplicationController
  def library_zones
  end
end
```

library_zones.coffee:

```
$("#zoneSelectionPlaceholder").html("<%= j(render 'library_zones') %>")
```

_library_zones.html.haml (notice I call the model BadName, trying to get an error):

```
= collection_select(:zones, :zone_id, BadName.library_zones, :id, :description, {prompt: 'Zone to Add...'}, {id: 'zoneToAddSelection'})
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :zones do
  collection do
    get 'library_zones
  end
end
```

spec:

```
RSpec.describe ZonesController, type: :controller do
  describe 'library_zones' do
    it 'renders library_zones.js template' do
      xhr :get, :library_zones
      expect(response).to render_template('library_zones')
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

All my specs are passing. I've tried introducing `haml` parse errors into the `_library_zones.html.haml` file as well as trying to introduce `js` errors into the `librarys_zones.coffee` file, but nothing seems to cause this test to fail.

- RSpec 3.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, controller specs do not render views unless you specifically enable it:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs/render-views